# Multiple Action Button not working in R shiny

Tags: shiny

I am new to R shiny and need your help. I want to use two action buttons (Yes and No) to take user feedback for a single question (is it sarcastic?) and send the response back to server.R. However, neither of the action buttons sends any response to the server. I just want server.R to know which of the Yes or No was chosen by the user. I don’t understand the reason behind it. Below is my code for ui.R and server.R, Thank you in advance for your help.

Ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
h3(titlePanel("Sarcasm Detection")),

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(width=6,
  h3("Enter your tweet:"),
  br(),

  textInput("text",""),
  submitButton("Check for Sarcasm"),

  hr(),
  strong(textOutput("text_output")),
  br(),
    p("Is it correct?"),      
   actionButton("yessarcasm","Yes"),
   actionButton("nosarcasm","No")
),
mainPanel(
  verbatimTextOutput("issarcasm")
  ))
))
```

Server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$text_output <- renderText({

 if(input$text %in% "sar"){
  "Yes, it is sarcastic"
}
else{
  "No, it is not sarcastic"
}

})

output$issarcasm <- renderText({
input$yessarcasm
input$nosarcasm
  if(input$yessarcasm != 0) {
    "User Feedback: Correct Prediction"
    }
  else if (input$nosarcasm != 0) {
    "User Feedback: Incorrect Prediction"
    }
})    
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies with `submitButton`. The documentation states that

> Forms that include a submit button do not automatically update their
>   outputs when inputs change, rather they wait until the user explicitly
>   clicks the submit button.

So when you have a `submitButton`, other inputs no longer update unless you press the submit button afterwards. Solution is to replace it with an actionButton, and use `observeEvent` in the server code.

in ui.R

```
actionButton("action", "Check for Sarcasm"),
```

in server.R

```
observeEvent(input$action, {
output$text_output <- renderText({

    if(input$text %in% "sar"){
        "Yes, it is sarcastic"
    }
    else{
        "No, it is not sarcastic"
    }

})
})
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked. I did not realise submit button was the reason behind the non-response of the two action button. The form now works as I expect. Thank you very much for your help.